# Django - Multiple <pk> in urls.py with DetailViews

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a script using [Django Generic display views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

**My urls.py**

```
url(r'^page/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PageDetails.as_view(), name='page-details'),
```

**My views.py**

```
class PageDetails(DetailView):
    model = Pages

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**The problem**
How can I set multi `<pk>` in my urls like this?

```
url(r'^page/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/subpage/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', PageDetails.as_view(), name='page-details'),
```

In my views I need to take data from first and second `<pk>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the second `pk` argument in your url to something else, for example `pk_alt`:

```
^page/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/subpage/(?P<pk_alt>[0-9]+)$
```

The url parameter `pk_alt` will then be available in your views function as part of the `self.kwargs` dictionary, so you can access it using:

```
self.kwargs.get('pk_alt', '')
```

You could then update your views to something like the following:

```
class PageDetails(DetailView):
    model = Pages

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        page_alt = Pages.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk_alt', ''))
        context['page_alt'] = page_alt
        return context
```

You will then be able to access the alternative model in your template using `{{ page_alt }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you need two arguments in the url try this:

```
url(r'^page/(?P<pk_1>[0-9]+)/subpage/(?P<pk_2>[0-9]+)$', PageDetails.as_view(), name='page-details'),
```

Then you have `pk_1` and `pk_2` available as `kwargs`